# Add jar files to classpath at launch time

Tags: java

I want to add some jar files to my binary at runtime, but I keep getting errors. I'm running this on a Windows machine. My code is in a directory called SeleniumTest.

Here is the command I used to compile:

```
javac SeleniumTest\src\com\src\test\First.java -d SeleniumTest\bin -cp SeleniumTest\lib\junit-4.10.jar;SeleniumTest\lib\selenium-java-2.39.0.jar;SeleniumTest\lib\selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar
```

This worked successfully. However when I try to run this command:

```
java -cp SeleniumTest\lib\junit-4.10.jar;SeleniumTest\lib\selenium-java-2.39.0.jar;SeleniumTest\lib\selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar SeleniumTest\bin com.src.test.First
```

I get a message:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class SeleniumTest\bin
```

My code, First.java exists in

```
SeleniumTest\bin\com\src\test
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you considered using [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/), [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) or [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) / [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) to manage your build and dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
java -cp "SeleniumTest\lib\junit-4.10.jar;SeleniumTest\lib\selenium-java-2.39.0.jar;SeleniumTest\lib\selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar;SeleniumTest\bin"  com.src.test.First
```

Comment: Does'nt work. Won't I need to specify the SeleniumTest directory?

Comment: @user1801060 What is the error printout for this example?

Comment: Where does `First.class` exist?

Comment: @Andremoniy: "Error: Could not find or load main class SeleniumTest\bin"

Comment: @Iaz: SeleniumTest\bin\com\src\test\First.class

Comment: It looks like you are missing the drive letters on all of those paths

Comment: @Iaz: I'm running using relative paths. If it worked during compile time, I believe it should work at runtime

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
java -cp SeleniumTest\lib\junit-4.10.jar;SeleniumTest\lib\selenium-java-2.39.0.jar;SeleniumTest\lib\selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar SeleniumTest\bin SeleniumTest\src\com\src\test\First
```

Comment: @satish-srg: "Error: Could not find or load main class SeleniumTest\bin\com\src\test\First"